# Why is the Javascript function not working with the parameters as written?

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript function that works perfectly fine when the var are set directly, using class names found on the page.

however when I try to call it from passed parameters (see the end of the code) , it is not working. I don't know why. EDIT: problem seems to be that the variables are not getting set properly... see comments at the beginning of the code...

also please note that I am still a beginner and am not certain if the words I use are the right terminology... if not please let me know. thanks

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    function contentChanger(parameters) {

        var displayersjs = document.querySelectorAll('parameters.titles');
        var displayedcontentjs = document.querySelectorAll('parameters.content');
   console.log(parameters.titles); //returns .displayers as expected
   console.log(parameters.content); //returns .displayedcontent as expected
   console.log(displayersjs[1]); //returns undefined, don't know why
   console.log(displayedcontentjs[1]); // also returns undefined

        var _loop = function _loop(i) {
            displayersjs[i].addEventListener('click', function () {


                if (!displayersjs[i].classList.contains('parameters.activetitle')) {
                    for (var j = 0, len = displayersjs.length; j < len; j++) {
                        displayersjs[j].classList.remove('parameters.activetitle');
                        displayedcontentjs[j].classList.add('parameters.nocontent');
                    }
                    displayersjs[i].classList.add('parameters.activetitle');
                    displayedcontentjs[i].classList.remove('parameters.nocontent');
                } else {

                }
            });
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < displayersjs.length; i++) {
            _loop(i);
        }
    }


    contentChanger({
        titles: '.displayers',
        content: '.displayedcontent',
        activetitle: 'clicked',
        nocontent: 'noshow'
    });


});
```

this exact same function works perfectly fine, when using written like this and using directly the class names

```
    'use strict';

   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var displayersjs = document.querySelectorAll('.displayers');
  var displayedcontentjs = document.querySelectorAll('.displayedcontent');

  var _loop = function _loop(i) {
    displayersjs[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      if (!displayersjs[i].classList.contains('clicked')) {
          for (var j = 0, len = displayersjs.length; j < len; j++) {
          displayersjs[j].classList.remove('clicked');
          displayedcontentjs[j].classList.add('noshow');
          }
        displayersjs[i].classList.add('clicked');
        displayedcontentjs[i].classList.remove('noshow');
      } else {

      }
    });
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < displayersjs.length; i++) {
    _loop(i);
  }

});
```

Comment: console.log (below the var declarations) is returning undefined...

Comment: Why are you declaring a function inside your event handler? It doesn't depend on anything in-scope that you only have available once the event triggers, so at the very least pull it out of that event handler and make it a function at the same depth as the addeventlistener. And now you can reduce your problem: either your function is broken, which you can test entirely without that document event trigger, or the function works, and you can entirely disregard it while further investigating. The same goes for _loop: declare it higher, and pass what it needs into it when calling.

Comment: Can you elaborate on specifically what "not working" means here?  This is a great time to start using your browser's debugging tools.  You can use the script debugger to place breakpoints that will pause execution of the code and allow you to step through line by line and observe the exact runtime behavior and changing values of your variables.  Where specifically does an operation first fail or produce an unexpected result?

Comment: If I were to *guess*, I'd say that this is just a typo.  I wouldn't expect this to find anything: `document.querySelectorAll('parameters.titles')`  Because there's no HTML element called `<parameters>`.  It looks like throughout your code you are using string literals where you meant to use object references.

Comment: alright... thanks for the answers! Mike, I admit I am not completely following you.. if you could quickly copy-paste my code and re organise it as you think is the better way, I would be very grateful...

David, I will look with the debugging... however console has no errors. and the `document.querySelectorAll('parameters.titles')` is working... I wrote earlier it was returning undefined, but now it is returning exactly what it should `.displayers`.

Comment: not working means that the classList add and remove functions are not adding and removing these classes...

Comment: Using the debugger I found that the problem is that even though `parameters.titles` returns the right value, if I console log `displayersjs[1]` it returns undefined ... I updated my post

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll('parameters.titles')` means that you search for `<parameters class="titles">`. The `parameters.titles` variable contains a string, so what you want to do is using the following code:

`document.querySelectorAll(parameters.titles)`

Now querySelectorAll will search for elements having the class `.displayers`.